# Can I resolve my toolchain version error with this package?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, calendarkit

I am trying to use the following package in a project:

https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit.git

When I try adding the package via the Swift Package Manager, I get an error about toolchain versions (please see the pic below). I am using XCode 12.4, and my computer is too old to install 12.5.

I tried installing the latest toolchain, but it did not resolve the problem:

[image: Old toolchain error next to new toolchain]

Does anyone know if I can get the package to recognize the v5 toolchain I installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the toolchain to `5.3`, so now there should be no problems of installing CalendarKit with that Swift Toolchain version.

Comment: Hi Richard - thanks for the answer! I did as you suggested and was able to add the package. I will submit a pull request as well.

Comment: OK, please submit the PR, feel free to mark this answer as accepted, since the library will be now supporting Swift Tools 5.3

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

In this case, repo tags can be your friend.

One of my own computers is also (hopefully only temporarily) stuck at Catalina and XCode 12.4, so I was able to add this package to a repo by specifying a (slightly) older version from the [list of tagged versions](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/tags):

[image: Enter In GitHub Repo URL]

[image: Enter Tag in here]

I entered in version 1.0.8 into the "Rules" section, but SPM picked up version 1.0.9, which is likely to be the last version that works with Xcode 12.4.

[image: And here it is, ready to go!]

Comment: Hi Michael - thanks for the answer! I will give this a shot. I did consider using an older version of the package. I was hoping to use the latest release. For example I noticed that a recent commit fixed a memory leak. Do you know if it's possible to get the package to recognize the new toolchain I installed? I think this is really what I've been wondering, I'll edit my question to reflect this!

Comment: Welp, there's a risk that something built targeting Swift 5.5 or Swift 6 just simply will refuse to compile with an older compiler.

Comment: Dang too bad. I guess it may be time to start saving for a new computer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm waiting for an appropriate M1-chipped desktop before I upgrade (just like you are). :-)